# How to get touch events working in chromium portable running in windows surface?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, touch, chromium-portable

This is what I am using to trigger the touch events :

```
var eventMap = {};

(function(){
  var eventReplacement = {
    "mousedown": ["touchstart mousedown", "mousedown" , "pointerdown"],
    "mouseup": ["touchend mouseup", "mouseup", "pointerup"],
    "click": ["touchstart click", "click"],
    "mousemove": ["touchmove mousemove", "mousemove", "pointermove"]
 };

for (i in eventReplacement) {
    if (typeof window["on" + eventReplacement[i][0]] == "object") {
        eventMap[i] = eventReplacement[i][0];
    } 
    else {
        eventMap[i] = eventReplacement[i][1];
        };
  };
})();
```

Then I use it as following:

```
$(genderSlider.pointer).on(eventMap.mousedown, setOffset);
$(genderSlider.pointer).on(eventMap.mousemove, fnMoveSlider);
$(genderSlider.pointer).on(eventMap.mouseup, function(event){event.preventDefault(); $(event.target).css("-webkit-opacity", "0.5");usingSlider = false});
```

Then the callback methods look somewhat like this :

```
function setOffset(event){ 

alert(event.type);
event.preventDefault();
alert(event.type);
var touch = '';
if (event.type == 'mousedown'){
    usingSlider = true;
    touch = event;
} else {
    usingSlider = true;
    alert(event.type);
    touch = event.originalEvent.touches[0];
}

var ypos = touch.pageY; // Get Y Coordinate
$(event.target).css("-webkit-opacity", "1.0");
offset = parseFloat(ypos) - parseFloat(this.style.top); 

refObj = {};

if(this.id === $(genderSlider.pointer).attr("id")){
        refObj = genderSlider;
   }
}
```

Things are working fine for mouse events. But for touch events the alert shows as mousevents. Tried `touch-action: none` as well. But does not work

Can anybody suggest what should I try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally made it work. May be useful for the future readers.

The solution was actually way easier than I actually perceived it to be. Does not make much sense though, but it actually works.

The solution was the following:

Wrote the method for two types of events separately, so it looked like:

```
$(genderSlider.pointer).on("mousedown", setOffset);
$(genderSlider.pointer).on("mousemove", fnMoveSlider);
$(genderSlider.pointer).on("mouseup", function(event)    {event.preventDefault(); $(event.target).css("-webkit-opacity", "0.5");usingSlider = false});
```

And again for touch :

```
$(genderSlider.pointer).on("touchstart", setOffsetForTouch);
$(genderSlider.pointer).on("touchmove", fnMoveSliderForTouch);
$(genderSlider.pointer).on("touchend", function(event)    {event.preventDefault(); $(event.target).css("-webkit-opacity", "0.5");usingSlider = false});
```

Then wrote the callback events separately to handle the cases differently.